# In split view controller master view controller not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to instantiate `SplitViewController` from another `UIViewController`; but I could not get the `MasterViewController` to show up on my `iPad`.

`MasterViewController` and `DetailViewController` are been added using storyboards.

Following is the code I have implemented:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_Ipad", bundle: nil);
let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigationID") as? UINavigationController;
let splitViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? UISplitViewController

self.view.window!.rootViewController = navigationController;
splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryHidden
splitViewController?.delegate = self

self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Portrait orientation?

Comment: I have it as Landscape only for ipad devices. Also when I add background color to viewdidload it works; but none of tableview or buttons are shown

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue...
I changed the auto-layout constraint on storyboard to wAnyhAny for iPad and added the constraints to that layout and not to wRHR which I was using it earlier....